# PHP form for sending mail is not working

Tags: php, html, email, ubuntu

I am using php form for sending email from my website but its not working. I am trying to send it from server(ubuntu). I am not getting what's the issue.

It would be grateful if anyone can help me with this.

This is the php code: **contactinfo.php**

```
---<html>
<head>
<title>Sending HTML email using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   $to = "xyz@gmail.com";
   $subject = "This is subject";
   $message = "<b> First Name :".$_POST['fname']."</b>";
   $message = "<b> Last Name :".$_POST['lname']."</b>";
   $message .= "<h1>Email ".$_POST['email'].".</h1>";
   $message .= "<h1>Website ".$_POST['website'].".</h1>";
   $message .= $_POST['message'];
   $header = "From:qwerty@gmail.io \r\n";
   $header = "Cc:abc@gmail.com \r\n";
   $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";   
   $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
   if( $retval == true )
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
      sleep(2);
      header("Location: http://xyz.co/"); /* Redirect browser */
      exit();
   } else {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
      sleep(2);
      header("Location:http://abc.co/"); /* Redirect browser */
      exit();
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the html code:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contactinfo.php">
    <div class="two_columns_50_50 clearfix">
        <div class="column1">
            <div class="column_inner">
                <input type="text" style="opacity: 0.8;" class="requiredField" name="fname" id="fname" value=""  placeholder="First Name *"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <div class="column_inner">
                <input type="text" style="opacity: 0.8;" class="requiredField" name="lname" id="lname" value="" placeholder="Last Name *" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="two_columns_50_50 clearfix">
        <div class="column1">
            <div class="column_inner">
                <input type="text" style="opacity: 0.8;" class="requiredField email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email *" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <div class="column_inner">
                <input type="text" style="opacity: 0.8;" name="website" id="website" value="" placeholder="Website"/>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="message" style="opacity: 0.8;" id="message" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

    <span class="submit_button_contact">
        <input class="qbutton contact_form_button" type="submit" value="Contact Us" style="opacity: 0.6; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: black;" />
    </span>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you working on localhost ?

Comment: I am working on server @GokulShinde

Comment: Turn on error reporting and tell us what you get.

Comment: try this simple script. save as mail.php and run  <?php
$to = "yourmaily@example.com";//give your email here
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>

Comment: According to code you provided, you getting message `"Message could not be sent..."`, right? or just email not found in you inbox?

Comment: email not found in inbox GokulShinde

Comment: try the code which I've sent. it will help to find the issue.

Comment: check in the spam.

Comment: do you've sendmail or smtp setup ?

Comment: check your server configuration and if the message should be encrypted or what it requires... (email service you are trying to reach). Check if there are no typos on your email addresses and the size of your message... in your inbox (sender inbox) is there any response from the server you are trying to reach?

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL I have already checked there are no typos, no size issues. No there is no response from the server.

Comment: The fact of the matter is this: 1) You're outputting before header. 2) Your header variables are different and the concatenates are broken for a few of them. Using error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have told you about that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't get you. Actually I am new to php and writing this script for the first time. So it would be good if you can explain me this more briefly.